# Vetor por Parâmetro em C

Tags: c, array, stack

Estou precisando passa a posição de Vetor por parâmetro como segue código, minha função recebe o endereço e modifica diretamente a variável passada por parâmetro.
Porém o programa para de funcionar e fecha durante a compilação. Alguém pode me ajuda??

```
for(i=10;i>=0;i++)
    FPVazia(&Buckets[i]);

void FPVazia(TipoPilha *Pilha)
```

Comment: Sempre inclua o código, não uma imagem com ele. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: O laço nunca para. Começa em 10 e vai sempre somando um, nunca se aproximando da condição de parada

Answer (score 0):

Quando se trabalha com vetores, não se deve colocar o & para passar o endereço de memória pois ele já recebe desta forma (somente com vetores).

Posta o restante do código, pois estás passando um elemento de vetor, mas na assinatura do método ele recebe uma estrutura de dados pilha.

Teu código pode ser assim:

```
for(i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    FPVazia(Buckets[i]);
```

Ou assim:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    FPVazia(Buckets[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste seu caso não é necessário colocar o `&` antes do vetor, vamos analisar o porque disso, sua função é a seguinte `void FPVazia(TipoPilha *Pilha)` note que o que você pede como parâmetro é um ponteiro para uma região da memória, este que será interpretado como um tipoPilha, e quando você o chama você está passando o seguinte, `FPVazia(&Buckets[i]);`, e porque isto está errado, aqui caímos na definição do que é vetor, um vetor é um ponteiro para uma região de memória, esta que seria a sua primeira região de memória do vetor, índice 0.

Então para facilitar o seu entendimento, para você entender melhor o que você fez, uma outra forma de escrever o que você fez é a seguinte  `FPVazia(&(TipoPilha*)(Buckets + i));`, logo você nota que o que você está passando para a sua função é o endereço de memória do seu ponteiro e não da posição do seu vetor, pois um vetor já é um ponteiro.

Para arrumar isto basta tirar este `&`, ficando da seguinte maneira  `FPVazia(Buckets[i]);` ou  `FPVazia((TipoPilha*)(Buckets + i));`, é importante ressaltar que estas duas maneiras são equivalentes, a unica diferença entre elas é que uma é omitido o ponteiro e a conta de posição, enquanto a outra não.

A segunda maneira é feita utilizando aritmética de ponteiro, um ponteiro `*` por si só sempre é interpretado como um inteiro em C, então para evitar que algum erro ocorra sempre quando estiver utilizando aritmética de ponteiros lembre-se de fazer o casting, para que o ponteiro seja interpretado de acordo com o tipo que você está utilizando, se a variável buckets fosse um vetor de inteiros você poderia deixar apenas `FPVazia(*(Buckets + i));`, mas como não é faça o casting. Outro fato importante é que como já dito anteriormente você fazer `Buckets[i]` ou `(TipoPilha*)(Buckets + i)` é a mesma coisa, eles são equivalentes, pois quando você faz `Buckets[i]` o que o computador interpreta e faz é `(TipoPilha*)(Buckets + i)`.

Outro erro que está explicito é o do `for`, você inicia o seu `i` em 10, e depois incrementa ele, só que sua condição diz que para `i >= 0` você vai fazer o que há dentro do `for`, mas está condição sempre será verdade logo o seu loop será infinito, para arrumar isto basta decrementar o seu `i`, ou você inicia o `i` em 0, na condição coloca `i < 10`, e dai incrementa o `i`.

Indo direto para a resposta, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
for ( i = 10 ; i >= 0; i-- )
    FPVazia(Buckets[i]);
```

ou

```
for ( i = 10 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
    FPVazia((TipoPilha*)(Buckets + i));
```

ou

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ )
    FPVazia(Buckets[i]);
```

ou

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    FPVazia((TipoPilha*)(Buckets + i));
```